# Return information from dict

Tags: python, django

I want to save object with minimum of code.

**in views (need only specific attributes):**

```
my_obj = Entry.create(name=my.name, ...)
```

**in models:**

```
@classmethod
def create(cls, **kwargs):
    return cls(name=kwargs['name'], ...)
```

Is there a way to shorten this code? Provide your examples.

Comment: `Entry.objects.get_or_create(name=my.name, ...)`

Comment: [`create` is already part of the queryset api](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/models/querysets/#create); you can remove your class method from `models.py`; and it is already short enough. Please describe an actual problem, otherwise this is better suited for [codegolf](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com).

Comment: @BurhanKhalid: but `model.objects.create()` also includes a `instance.save()` call.

Comment: @MartijnPieters _"I want to save object with minimum of code."_

Comment: @BurhanKhalid: Yet the sample code he provides *does not use `.save()`*. So we need to make it explicit that there is a difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make this more generic with:

```
@classmethod
def create(cls, **kwargs):
    return cls(**{k: kwargs[k] for k in kwargs.viewkeys() & cls._meta.get_all_field_names()})
```

which filters the keyword arguments to just those for which there are fields.

Or just trust that no extra keyword arguments were passed in and use:

```
@classmethod
def create(cls, **kwargs):
    return cls(**kwargs)
```

If you also wanted the save the newly-created object (`my_obj.save()`) you could use the [`model.objects.create()` method](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/querysets/#create):

```
@classmethod
def create(cls, **kwargs):
    return cls.objects.create(**{k: kwargs[k] for k in kwargs.viewkeys() & cls._meta.get_all_field_names()})
```

or unfiltered:

```
@classmethod
def create(cls, **kwargs):
    return cls.objects.create(**kwargs)
```